# Vue.JS: use variable & axios in mounted()?

Tags: vue.js, axios

my goal is to create an overlay filled with data fetched by axios when the overlay is mounted. I tried it like so but am not able to use it with a variable ( *.get("/edit/" + id* ) but it works with a hardcoded value (*.get("/edit/" + "123")*):

```js
<script>
Vue.component("qm-overlay", {
  data() {
    return {
      myid : '123',
    };
  },

  props: {
    [..] 
  },

  mounted() {
      axios
        .get("/edit/" + myid )
        .then(response => (this.overlaydata = response.data));
  },


  methods: {
[..] 
  },

  template: `
        <div id="overlay"> [..] /div>
        `
});
</script>
```

The errors I get in the browser console are:

- **[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: myid is not defined"**
- **ReferenceError: "myid not defined"**

**Question**: Isn't 'myid' defined properly in "data"? What am I doing wrong?

My setting is: Laravel 5.6 and Vue.js with axios. The used URL in axios is created in laravel and working.
In the blade file of laravel I call the component with

```html
<qm-overlay></qm-overlay>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.myid` instead of `myid` to access.